# Github search bar element not interactable issue

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webautomation

I am trying to use selenium and writing a simple code which will open the browser and go to github website. After opening the page it will search a given keyword in the search bar, but the issue is that when I run the code it is showing the element not interactable. This happening so because I am not being able to find the search bar element probably due to java script [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP8MF.png).

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
url = "http://github.com"
driver.get(url)
searchInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='query-builder-test']")
time.sleep(1)
searchInput.send_keys("python")
time.sleep(2)
searchInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

I tried using javascript executor to select the input element and also used selenium find element method but not being able to search the keyword [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kch9Z.png).

```
element=driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('query-builder-test').value='python';")
searchInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='query-builder-test']")
```

Comment: Please never post code as images, simply copy/paste your code into the question and format it as code. If you need any help, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i can see the GitHub search bar is a button element. i would suggest:

```
driver.maximize_window()
WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
search_buttons = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "header-search-button")
print(search_buttons.text)
search = search_buttons
search.click()
```

I would suggest learning some HTML as it makes using Selenium 100x easier

Hey Here's my updated answer this now clicks on the search bar and should now allow you to type in some text let me know how it goes i tested it out and seems to be working on my end.

Comment: After selecting the search button I have targeted the input tag and can search the input keyword after that I can print the search results. Thanks for the help. input=driver.find_element(By.ID, "query-builder-test")
input.send_keys('python')
input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

Comment: Im very happy to hear that! great work :D. let me know if you need anything else happy codeing :)